# Mbrola.base is undefined

Tags: java, freetts, mbrola

I am trying to use the Freetts text to speech api.I have included all the jar files into my project.I have also copied the speech.properties file into home folder.But I am getting
an error **System property mbrola.base undefined.Will not use mbrola voices.**.Plus when i am  running the example jar files same error with no voice output.

How do I sort this?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236562/mbrola-voices-with-freetts-windows